# Peewee select elements where child does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, peewee

I am operating on a database with computers and and their processes.

I want to select computers that lack a process with name 'proc'.

See my attempt below:

```
from peewee import *

mysql_db = MySQLDatabase('dbname', host='host', port=3306, passwd='passwd')

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = mysql_db

class Computers(BaseModel):
    computerid = IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    name = CharField()

class Processes(BaseModel):
    processid = BigIntegerField(primary_key = True)
    computerid = ForeignKeyField(Computers, backref = 'processes', db_column='computerid')
    name = CharField()

mysql_db.connect()

proc_computers = (Computers
        .select(Computers, Processes)
        .join(Processes)
        .where(Processes.name == 'proc')
        )

non_proc_computers = (Computers
            .select()
            .where(Computers.computerid.not_in(lttray_computers))
            )
```

This results in `peewee.InternalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')`

Could somebody point me to what I seem to be doing wrong?  I am trying to follow the docs here: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/query_operators.html

Is there a better way to be doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want to use EXISTS:

```
subq = Process.select().where(
    (Process.name == 'proc') &
    (Process.computer == Computer.id))

query = Computer.select().where(~fn.EXISTS(subq))
```

Note: it's a best practice not to use plural form for model classes. Similarly, not to include "xxx_id" in your field names.

Comment: Thanks very much -- haven't gotten a chance to fix this (developed a workaround) but I'll give it a go.

I know it's not best practice to use plurals but I'm interfacing with a shitty preexisting DB and am keeping consistent.